# Do methods count as function expressions?

Tags: javascript

A function declaration looks like:

```
function declaration() {}
```

and a function expression looks like:

```
const expression = function() {};
```

If I had to choose, methods count as function expressions? My reasoning is because they are not hoisted like function declarations and the name is omitted to the right of the `function` keyword.

```
let foo = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log('foo.bar()');
  }
};
```

or are methods counted as their own separate category?

Answer (score 1):

That is an object literal in which you declare keys and values using *expressions.* Yes, that is a function expression. For it to be not an expression it would need a) a name (`function foo() {}`) and b) to be by itself on its own line as a *statement*, not part of a larger expression.

Answer (score -1):

Everything boils down to Objects and prototypes. It's more of a Function reference in a prototype object:

```js
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.greet = function () {};
console.log(Person.prototype.greet);

Person.prototype.greet = new Function('');
console.log(Person.prototype.greet);

Person.prototype.greet = greet;
function greet() {}
console.log(Person.prototype.greet);

new Person().greet();//works either way
```

You can reference a function expression or a function declaration. All in all, it's just a Function object.

Comment: Actually, my idea of "methods" was influenced by [MDN's definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_expressions); "A method is a function that is a property of an object"

Comment: It's apparent your idea is *more* than what you've quoted and only reinforces my answer's correctness.

Comment: It's not about being smart or not, Mi. It's the truth. You shouldn't be offended by that.

Comment: You're right, it's about answering the original question, which you have not - at least not in a coherent way (the question is a yes or no question meaning there should be a yes or no answer).

Comment: The answer is both, Mi. I showed two examples of either case where the property is assigned to a function expression or a function declaration. It doesn't matter. Either way, it's just a Function object.

Answer (score -1):

you can declear a method of an object like this:

```js
let foo ={
name:'foo',
sayHello(){
console.log(this.name+'hello')
}
}
foo.sayHello() //  foohello
```

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question. Also, you might want to indent your code.